# My program of Top K frequent element keeps on giving runtime error

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++17, c++14

So today I was solving a leetcode problem : 'Top K frequent element' but I am getting runtime error while
running the code . Please help me solve this problem , as I am stuck on this.
My code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> topKFrequent(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        unordered_map<int,int> m;
        for(int i = 0 ; i<nums.size() ; i++)
        {
                int key = nums[i];
                if(m.find(key)==m.end())
                    m.insert({key,1});
                else
                    m.at(key) +=1;
        }
        vector<pair<int,int>> v;
        for(auto x : m)
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(x.second,x.first));
        }
        vector<int> sol;
        sort(v.begin(),v.end());
        for(int i = v.size()-1 ; i>=k-1 ; i++)
        {
            sol.push_back(v[i].second);
        }
        return sol;
    }
};
```

sample input : nums = 1 1 1 2 2 3 , k = 2.
output : [1,2]

But my code is giving runtime error.

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: fwiw, the complete first loop can be replaced by `for (const auto& n : nums) ++m[key];`

Comment: `int i = v.size()-1` is suspicious to wrap around and might cause running out of memory

Comment: I have used a variable instread of v.size(), still it is giving runtime error

Comment: fwiw, if you want to find the issue, you would first create a complete example that reproduces the crash: https://godbolt.org/z/1n5oKfzT5, then you would use a debugger to see where the code goes off the rails

Comment: typo : `i++` -> `--i`

Comment: ^^^ That. Also, note that you could sort a vector in descending order. Consider playing with [`nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) too.

Comment: *Top K frequent element* -- FYI --For the `vector` loop, you could build a min-heap of `K` items instead of duplicating all of the map items in the vector.  Imagine if `K` was small, and the total number of items in the map is very large.

Comment: ***But my code is giving runtime error*** For a good question you need to always tell us the exact message about the error as it can be very important. And also you should have used a debugger to test (step through your code line by line looking at the variables and flow) after you got an error on a website. You would have to do a little work to make the code into a complete program but it should not be that difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you accidently use `i++` in your last loop. So, the index grows more and more and will eventually go out of bounds.

To fix this, you must decrement "i", so `--i`

There are so many possible solutions, that it is hard to find a good one.

E.g. You can also use an even easier solution by employing the `std::partial_sort_copy`-function.

But as said, many many potential solutions possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

auto topKFrequent(std::vector<int>& nums, size_t k) {

    // Count occurences
    std::unordered_map<int, size_t> counter{};
    for (const int& i : nums) counter[i]++;

    // For storing the top k
    std::vector<std::pair<int, size_t>> top(k);

    // Get top k
    std::partial_sort_copy(counter.begin(), counter.end(), top.begin(), top.end(),
        [](const std::pair<int, size_t >& p1, const std::pair<int, size_t>& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; });

    return top;
}
// Test code
int main() {
    std::vector data{ 1,1,1,2,2,3 };

    for (const auto& [value, count] : topKFrequent(data, 2))  std::cout << value << ' ';
}
```

This will produce "1 2" as output.